# Regex character exclusion

Tags: regex, powershell, regex-negation

I am trying to validate a string that contains one or more tokens with the format `[Item~SomeNameHere]` with subversion of that token being `[Item~Incerement***]` where the `***` are a number of possibilities that I will further validate later. The key is that the Increment token must be the final token in the string.
So `[Item~Increment]` is valid, and `_[Item~modifiedDate][Item~Increment(#)]` is valid but `_[Item~Increment(#)][Item~modifiedDate]` is invalid. The goal is a very flexible breadcrumb functionality, where these tokens will then be replaced with other data for the final file or folder name.

To that end I started with this Regex, `\[Item~Increment.*\]`, which does find the token in the string. So I modified it to look for the token at the end of the string with `\[Item~Increment.*\]$` and that works, until and example like `[Item~Increment(#)][Item~modifiedDate]` where `.*` matches `(#)][Item~modifiedDate` and produces True where a False is needed. Somehow I need `.` any character, not including `[` or `]`, zero or more times. But `\[Item~Increment[.-\[\]]*\]$` is not getting the job done, and I am now well out of my RegEx depth. I have also tried just a negation with `\[Item~Increment[^\[\]]*\]$` and it also fails, as in always false.

EDIT: To clarify, the Increment token can occur only once and only at the end. However, there could be other tokens of the form `[Item~???]` or `[???~???]` earlier in the string, and there could be literal characters as well. So `-[Some~String]_[Item~Date]_[Item~Increment]` is valid.
Based on the answer from @wiktor-stribiżew I have refined things a bit, and transcribed to PowerShell nomenclature, and I now have this...

```
$breadcrumbs = @('none', '[Item~Increment]', '[Item~Increment(#)]', '[Item~modifiedDate][Item~Increment(#)]', '[Item~Increment][Item~modifiedDate]', '[Item~Increment][Item~Increment]')
$pattern = '(?:\[Item~[^][]*])*\[Item~Increment[^][]*]$'

CLS
foreach ($breadcrumb in $breadcrumbs) {
    Write-Host "$([regex]::matches($breadcrumb, $pattern).Count) $breadcrumb"
}
```

producing...

```
0 none
1 [Item~Increment]
1 [Item~Increment(#)]
1 [Item~modifiedDate][Item~Increment(#)]
0 [Item~Increment][Item~modifiedDate]
1 [Item~Increment][Item~Increment]
```

<s>In theory, the first should fail because there is no Increment token</s> In theory the first one should pass, as there is no incorrect token, the last should fail because there are two Increment tokens, and the next to last should fail because there is one Increment token that isn't at the end of the string.

But this RegEx fails on that final test, I assume because `[Item~Increment][Item~Increment]` is being matched as

`[Item~Increment`
`][Item~Increment`
`]`

where `][Item~Increment` is the variable content.

Is this me transcribing to PowerShell incorrectly? Or does the RegEx need a bit more to ensure that `[` and `]` cannot occur inside the token, and thus this example would produce a count of two or a failure. I don't mind needing another test for count, because that's a useful error to produce for users. But as it stands I get a count of 1, which is not valid.

EDIT2: Doj's answer is also interesting, and shorter as well. Using `\[Item~Increment[^\[\]]*\]` I get a count of 2 for the last example, but the order is not handled. Revise it to end of sting like this `\[Item~Increment[^\[\]]*\]$` and the order is handled, but multiples no longer are. Ugh.

EDIT3: Combining the two patterns based on Doj's answer gets me to this

```
foreach ($breadcrumb in $breadcrumbs) {
    $incrementCount = ([regex]::matches($breadcrumb, '\[Item~Increment[^\[\]]*\]')).Count
    if ($incrementCount -eq 0) {
        Write-Host "$breadcrumb good"
    } elseif ($incrementCount -gt 1) {
        Write-Host 'Duplicate [Item~Increment] tokens'
    } else {
        if (([regex]::matches($breadcrumb, '\[Item~Increment[^\[\]]*\]$')).Count -ne 0) {
            Write-Host "$breadcrumb good"
        } else {
             Write-Host '[Item~Increment] token not at the end of the string'
        }
    }
}
```

which produces...

```
none good
[Item~Increment] good
[Item~Increment(#)] good
[Item~modifiedDate][Item~Increment(#)] good
[Item~Increment] token not at the end of the string
Duplicate [Item~Increment] tokens
```

and I am off to the races!

EDIT4: Because learning two ways to do things is always better than just one, I modified Wiktor's approach for PS, like so...

```
$breadcrumbs = @('none', '[Item~Increment]', '[Item~Increment%]', '[Item~modifiedDate][Item~Increment%]', '[Item~Increment][Item~modifiedDate]', '[Item~Increment][Item~Increment%]', '[Item~Increment]_')

CLS
foreach ($breadcrumb in $breadcrumbs) {
if ($breadcrumb -match '\A(?:\[Item~(?!Increment[^][]*])[^][]*])*\[Item~Increment[^][]*]\z') {
    Write-Host "$breadcrumb good"
} else {
    Write-Host "!!! $breadcrumb"
}
```

}

This produces an incorrect result for none.

!!! none
[Item~Increment] good
[Item~Increment%] good
[Item~modifiedDate][Item~Increment%] good
!!! [Item~Increment][Item~modifiedDate]
!!! [Item~Increment][Item~Increment%]
!!! [Item~Increment]_

I thought there where two incorrect results, but I had used the wrong pattern. :(

Comment: Not a Powershell person, but generally `]` needs to be the first character in a character class, or second after `^` in a negated character class.

Comment: `'_[Item~modifiedDate][Item~Increment(#)]' -match '\[Item~Increment[^\[\]]*\]$'` returns `True`, and `'_[Item~Increment(#)][Item~modifiedDate]' -match '\[Item~Increment[^\[\]]*\]$'` returns `False`. This is what you want, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```cs
\A(?!.*\[Item~[^][]*])|\A(?:\[Item~(?!Increment[^][]*])[^][]*])*\[Item~Increment[^][]*]\z
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!.*%5c%5bItem%7e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29.*%7c%5e%28%3f%3a%5c%5bItem%7e%28%3f!Increment%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29*%5c%5bItem%7eIncrement%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%5cr%3f%24&i=none%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%25%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7emodifiedDate%5d%5bItem%7eIncrement%25%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%5d%5bItem%7emodifiedDate%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%5d%5bItem%7eIncrement%25%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%5d_&o=m).

*Details*:

- `\A(?!.*\[Item~[^][]*])` - at the start of the string, check if there is `[Item~...]` substring after any zero or more chars other than LF chars as many as possible, and if found, fail the match
- `|` - or
- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group (a container for a pattern sequence to quantify):

  - `\[Item~` - a `[Item~` substring
  - `(?!Increment[^][]*])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `Increment` string, then zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char immediately to the right of the current position
  - `[^][]*` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]`
  - `]` - a `]` char
- `)*` - repeat the pattern sequence zero or more times
- `\[Item~Increment` - a `\[Item~Increment` string
- `[^][]*]` - zero or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]` char
- `\z` - the very end of string.

If you do not want to use that big pattern and need to provide two different error messages, you can unwrap the alternations into separate regex checks.

See this Powershell demo:

```
$rx_1 = '\[Item~[^][]*]' # Item is in string check
$rx_2 = '\A(?:\[Item~[^][]*])*\[Item~Increment[^][]*]\z' # II must be at the end of string
$rx_3 = '\[Item~Increment[^][]*](?!\z)' # II not at the end of string
foreach ($breadcrumb in $breadcrumbs) {
    if ($breadcrumb -notmatch $rx_1) {  # If no Item is in string
        Write-Host "$breadcrumb good"   # It is valid
    } else {
        if ($breadcrumb -match $rx_2) {         # If the string only contains Items
            if ($breadcrumb -notmatch $rx_3) {  # ...and no II is found not at the end
                Write-Host "$breadcrumb good"   # it is good
            } else {
                Write-Host 'An [Item~Increment] token not at the end of the string!'
            }
        } else {
             Write-Host 'No [Item~Increment] token at the end of the string or invalid format!'
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: So close. But as you see in the revised OP, I am still getting a bad result when the Increment token is doubled up. But I am working in PowerShell, and transcribing to PowerShell nomenclature may have broken things.

Comment: @Gordon From your edit, I see you are not using my solution. My second regex only allows *one* `[Item~Increment...]` at the end of string only. Please try *my* solution and let know what is not working. Also, why `[regex]::Matches`? To check if a string matches a regex, in PS, you need to just use `$isMatched = $breadcrumb -match $regex` (replace `-match` with `-cmatch` if you need case sensitive matching).

Comment: I updated the OP to show in more detail where I am failing with your approach. Pretty sure it's related to my transposing to PowerShell, but not sure where I am going wrong. Though I did just try yours exactly with \A not ^ & \z not $, and I get the same incorrect results. I didn't know those where options for string start and end! Gonna learn THREE things. :)

Comment: @Gordon But you used the first regex, I suggested using the **second** one, `\A(?:\[Item~(?!Increment[^][]*])[^][]*])*\[Item~Increment[^][]*]\z`, see [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3a%5c%5bItem%7e%28%3f!Increment%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29*%5c%5bItem%7eIncrement%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%5cr%3f%24&i=none%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%25%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7emodifiedDate%5d%5bItem%7eIncrement%25%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%5d%5bItem%7emodifiedDate%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%5d%5bItem%7eIncrement%25%5d%0d%0a%5bItem%7eIncrement%5d_&o=m).

Comment: The only "valid" strings are 1) `[Item~Increment]`, 2) `[Item~Increment%]` and 3) `[Item~modifiedDate][Item~Increment%]`. Is it the expected output?

Comment: Ack, yeah, I used the wrong one. Did it during first coffee. :( So, yes, those three should be good, as well as the first one with no tokens, `none`. The last three in the variation using your second pattern (now updated in the OP) should all be invalid for different reasons.

Comment: @Gordon So a string not containing `[Item~...]` is also valid? Then you can use `\A(?!.*\[Item~[^][]*])|\A(?:\[Item~(?!Increment[^][]*])[^][]*])*\[Item~Increment[^][]*]\z`

Comment: That final pattern does the trick. I suspect I might still stick with the other solution because 1: I can more easily provide a good error message for the different conditions, and 2: the simpler RegEx will be easier to come back to in a few months or years. But I think deconstruction this pattern and fully understanding it will do a LOT more for my understanding of RegEx in general.

Comment: @Gordon I can split it into 2 `if...else`s for you.

Comment: happy to see that solution as well. Nothing like starting from complex and then breaking it into logical parts to help really understand the starting point. RegEx still makes my brain hurt. :)

Comment: @Gordon Well, If you were more precise with the number of checks you need, I could provide a  more customized solution, but I think this is already usable.

Comment: Yeah, I definitely wasn't clear initially on the need for no token to be valid. As it is now it's fining all the failures of Increment not the last and increment duplicated. And maybe I can figure out for myself how to address catching those two failure modes. One thing that I think might be helpful to myself and others is a comparison with the other much simpler pattern, as I am sure there are some situation that pattern might miss that yours catches. I am really trying to understand the pro's and con's of each.

Comment: @Gordon I believe your original question is answered, if you need more specific help, please either edit the question.